# Parents Selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css

For example HTML :

```
<div id="css">
   <a href="/forum"></a>
</div>
```

How can I choose the parent selector of a href ?
I have tried :

```
#css! > a[href*="/forum"]
```

But not successful . Thanks for your helping

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) help?

Comment: I don't think CSS has a parent selector as of now. It was proposed to be included in CSS4.

Comment: there is no parent selector till now.

Comment: @Mateusz I can't find any solution on it . Specially ,  CSS4 doesn't support any browser

Comment: There is no CSS solution. That's why you can't find any.